# understanding usage of Constructor in bootstrap plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys was just going through the source code of [dropdown.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L143) and came across the following line of code , i see this line of code in all bootstrap plugins :

```
$.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown
```

can somebody explain what this line of code is doing , scanning through the js file i also see .

$(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) {

```
e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[role="menu"]', 

Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[role="listbox"]', 

Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
```

where i guess that line of code is probably being used , but i am still not sure , can somebody please explain ? the line of code can be found on [git](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L143) too.

thank you.

Tenali.

Comment: looks like it's mostly un-used ("Constructor" is not a pre-defined JS concept, just a custom property), but does provide a script-reachable duplicate in case you want to extend it or sub-class it yourself or to upgrade.

Comment: @dandavis , i would appreciate a slightly more elaborate answer ! :) thanks !

Comment: well, i didn't write the code, so i'm not sure why the "Constructor" property is there, it's not documented or obvious from the context. looking at the full bs JS, only a couple plugins actually use such a property and dropdown is not one of them. it looks like a backwards-compatible thing to me, but i'm not 100% sure. if you don't need it, i wouldn't lose sleep over it. understanding everything is nice, but you need to know when to accept the things you cannot control.

Comment: @dandavis , I'am not loosing any sleep . peace .

Comment: Note also the almost complete lack of semicolons. I wonder if `$.fn.dropdown.Constructor` is used by some bespoke transpiler or linter or aggregator tool at Twitter.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 , thx , nd yh i am aware of the semi colon issue , but thats hw its coded nd i can't do much abt it ..

Comment: Plain English please.

Comment: @guys if ur not going to contribute to the answer please BUzzzzzzzzzzzzz-off !! . and stop commenting !